# Matrix question: implication of $\frac{1}{n}X'X\to M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, economics

Suppose $K$ is fixed and consider a matrix $X$ that is $n\times K$ and has full column rank. Assume that we know
$$
\frac{1}{n}X'X\to M\text{ as } n\to\infty.\tag{i}
$$
That is, as $n$ becomes larger, we add more rows to $X$ in such a way that $X$ still has full column rank and (i) holds. It is given that $M$ is a fixed positive definite matrix with all of its eigenvalues in $(b,B)$ with some $0<b<B$.

Now, let $X_i$ be the $K\times 1$ vector such that $X'_i$ is the $i$-th row of $X$. Does it follow that

> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|X_i|^2=0?\tag{ii} $$

I tried looking at
$$
\frac{1}{n}X'X=\frac{1}{n}\begin{pmatrix}X_1&\cdots& X_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X'_1\\\cdots\\X'_n\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_iX'_i\to M.\tag{iii}
$$
It seems intuitive that each summand in (iii) has to be "small" and perhaps that will eventually leads me to (ii) but I can't produce a decent argument. Can someone help please?

---

**Edit**: I also looked at
$$
\text{Tr}\left(\frac{1}{n}X'X\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\text{Tr}(X_iX_i')=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i |X_i|^2\to\text{Tr}(M)\tag{iv}
$$
but I reached a deadend here too.

Comment: Just a comment to simplify things: the question boils down to this: if $\{a_n\}$ is sequence of nonnegative numbers such that $\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ equals some finite $L$, does it follow that $\frac{1}{n}\max_{1\leq i\leq n}a_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observe,
$$
\text{Tr}\left(\frac{1}{n}X'X\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\text{Tr}(X_iX_i')=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\text{Tr}(X_i'X_i)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i|X_i|^2.
$$
So $\frac{1}{n}X'X\to M$ implies $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i|X_i|^2\to\text{Tr}{M}$ with the latter being a positive number in $(Kb, KB)$. Then, the claim
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|X_i|\right)^2=0
$$
follows from the results discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/950763/136641).