# What does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X'X}{n}=Q$ imply?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Suppose $X$ is a $n \times m$ matrix with elements $x_{ij}$ and 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X'X}{n}=Q,$$ where $Q$ is positive definite. Let $x_i$ be the $i$-th row vector of $X$. For fixed $m$, a conjecture is $$\max_{i=1, ..., n} x_i'(X'X)^{-1}x_i =0, \text{ as } n \to \infty.$$

For $m=1$, it can be proved. But how to prove or disprove in a general case? This might be related [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950390/matrix-question-implication-of-frac1nxx-to-m)

Comment: $Q$ is not a matrix. You should specify where this $Q$ lives.

Comment: First of all, right now $n$ is is both the number of rows in $X$ and the denominator of $X'X/n$. Should those be the same number?  Second, does $x_i$ denote the $i$th column of $X$? Please clarify

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks for addressing one of my questions, but again: should those be the same number?

Comment: I have added $x_i$ above. But I don't know your first question.

Comment: @JohnSmith You write $n \to \infty$, but $X$ is $n \times m$. Does the size of $X$ change as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Upon reconsideration of your question, I believe that you are trying to ask the following.

> Fix elements $x_{ij}$ for $i = 1,\dots,m$ and $j = 1,2,3,\dots$.  Let $X_n$ denote the $n \times n$ matrix with entries $x_{ij}$. If
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_n'X_n}{n}=Q,$$ 
>   where $Q$ is positive definite, is it true that for every column $x_i$ of $X$, we have
>   $$
> \max_{i=1, ..., n} x_i'(X_n'X_n)^{-1}x_i =0, \text{ as } k \to \infty?
> $$

If this is what you meant, please say so.

For this version of the question, the conjecture is correct. In particular,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_i'(X_n'X_n)^{-1}x_i = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n x_i'\left(\frac{X_n'X_n}{n}\right)^{-1}x_i=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n x_i'Qx_i = 0.
$$

---

I assume that what you're trying to say is something like this:

> Suppose that for $k > 0$, $X(k)$ is a $n \times m$ matrix with elements $x_{ij}$ and 
>   $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{X'(k)X(k)}{k}=Q,$$ where $Q$ is positive definite. A conjecture is $$\max_{i=1, ..., n} x_i'(X'(k)X(k))^{-1}x_i =0, \text{ as } k \to \infty.$$

The answer to this question is no.  For example, take $X(k) = \sqrt{k}I$. Then $\max_{i=1,\dots,n}x_i'(X'(k)X(k))^{-1}x_i = 1$ for all $k$.

---

For an more general example (with a non-square $X$), take $X(k) = \pmatrix{\sqrt{k}I_n & 0_{n \times (m-n)}}$. Again, we find that $\max_{i=1,\dots,n}x_i'(X'(k)X(k))^{-1}x_i = 1$ for all $k$.

Comment: $X$ is a $n\times m$ matrix with $m$ fixed. But you incorrectly assumed $m=n$. Therefore, your counter example was not correct.

Comment: @JohnSmith The question you asked (as far as I understood it) is "does this conjecture hold in general", i.e. regardless of whether $m=n$. Therefore, my counterexample disproves your conjecture as it is currently stated.  Regardless, it's easy enough to generalize the example to arbitrary sizes

Comment: I should have made it clearer that $m$ is fixed but $n\to \infty$. So letting $m=n$ and $n \to \infty$ would violate the assumption. Thanks

Comment: Note that if $x_i$ is a row-vector, then $x_i' (X'X)^{-1} x_i$ is not defined because of a mismatch in the matrix sizes.

Comment: $x_i$ is $m\times 1$, so $x_i'$ is $1\times m$; $X'X$ is $m\times m$. Sorry, but I missed the point of a mismatch in the matrix sizes.

Comment: @JohnSmith never mind, you're right.